# Sed command in makefile

Tags: sed, makefile

I get a Input String from `@read` command in makefile.

```
@read -p "Enter Web Url:" weburl; \
```

I want to use the weburl variable in my below sed command in makefile.

```
@read -p "Enter Web Url:" weburl; \
sed 's/^\(ServerName:\)$/\1 $$weburl/' $(LOCALCONFIGDIR)/myfile.conf
```

But It is not executing the sed command after reading the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with `$` sign in Makefile, especially when used in a shell statement.
You can replace your `sed` command with this:

```
sed 's/^\(ServerName:\)$$/\1 '$$weburl'/' $(LOCALCONFIGDIR)/myfile.conf
```

Note the end of the line is `$$`. Note also that variable substitution can't be done with single quote `'`, that's why the variable is outside of it.

With some `sed` optimisation,  I'd rather advise you this:

```
sed "/^ServerName:/s/$$/ $$weburl/" $(LOCALCONFIGDIR)/myfile.conf
```

Comment: Putting the URL outside of any quotes is unadvisable, as the shell will attempt to do wildcard expansion and whitespace tokenization of unquoted values. But the double-quote answer is good.